# No hit sounds in Team Fortress 2

Tags: technical-issues, team-fortress-2

When I shoot an enemy in team fortress 2, there's no hit sound, and in the advanced options I turned it on and off multiple times and get the same result, please help.

Comment: Back in the day I had this happen to me and it could be fixed by starting/stopping a recording.

Comment: How do you start or stop a recording?

Answer (score 0):

Try entering these commands into the console:

```
tf_dingaling_pitch_override 0
tf_dingaling_pitchmaxdmg 100
tf_dingaling_pitchmindmg 100
tf_dingaling_volume 1
tf_dingalingaling 1
tf_dingalingaling_effect 0
tf_dingalingaling_repeat_delay 0
```